# What's suppressing my preprocessor #warnings?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, vxworks

I am porting a project from VxWorks 5.x to 7 and the new version of the "gcc" (4.8.1) compiler is not displaying the "#warning" statements within my C code.

The following are the flags I am using and none of them appear to inhibit the warning messages:

-march=corei7 -mpopcnt -maes -mpclmul -mavx -mfsgsbase -mrdrnd -mf16c -mavx2 -mmovbe -mfma -mbmi -mbmi2 -mrdseed -madx -mprfchw -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-defer-pop -m64 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mcmodel=$(CM) -mno-red-zone -fno-implicit-fp -ansi  -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss -O2 -w -g -w

I even added '-Wall' and that had NO affect.  If I replaced on of the '#warning's with '#error', the build fails, indicating that the code IS getting compiled.

Can anybody assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options):

```
-w    Inhibit all warning messages.
```

You have two of those in your command line.

Comment: Thanks Carl.  I guess this can be marked up as "can't see the forest for the trees"